# Javascript replace doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string like this,

```
var myVariable = 'Some string {} value';
```

I'm trying to change {} with a span tag.

```
myVariable.replace('{}', <span></span>);
```

it returns object object. I couldn't find a solution the easy way. I'm using like this but I don't think it's good.

```
myVariable.split('{}')[0]
<span></span>
myVariable.split('{}')[1]
```

what's your problems guys? why i want to write there string ? i want to write there span tag and i'm gonna add something in this.

Comment: `replace` expects a string as the second argument (or a function returning a string).

Comment: replace also returns a new string

Comment: With your edit it just makes the question even more unclear , what do you mean by " my span tag has class and has text"

Comment: if i use like this, {}, '<span></span>' i can't use span tag a tag it's returns a string value.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass **`'<span></span>'`** which is of type **`string`**

```js
var myVariable = 'Some string {} value';
var result= myVariable.replace('{}', '<span></span>');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: i don't want to write there span with string i want to change {} with span tag.

Comment: what do you mean? what is the expected ouput?

Comment: Do you want a DOM element instead of a string there?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot the quotes around your `span` (which is a `String`). Try:

```
myVariable.replace('{}', '<span></span>');
```

Comment: its not the only problem this code has, you need to put the return in a variable too

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 problem with your code :

- You forgot to put quotes around `'<span></span>'` so replace wouldn't know its a string
- Replace returns a string so you need to affect the result to a variable

Here is a snippet with your errors corrected :

```js
var stringVariable = 'Here is a Random string {} Chain';
var result= stringVariable.replace('{}', '<span></span>');
console.log(result);
```